# PySpark Column Creation by queuing filtered past rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark, I want to make a new column in an existing table that stores the last K texts for a particular user that had label 1.

```
    Example-

      Index | user_name |  text  | label   |
       0    |    u1     |   t0   |   0     |
       1    |    u1     |   t1   |   1     |
       2    |    u2     |   t2   |   0     |
       3    |    u1     |   t3   |   1     |
       4    |    u2     |   t4   |   0     |
       5    |    u2     |   t5   |   1     |
       6    |    u2     |   t6   |   1     |
       7    |    u1     |   t7   |   0     |
       8    |    u1     |   t8   |   1     |
       9    |    u1     |   t9   |   0     |
```

The table after the new column (text_list) should be as follows, storing last K = 2 messages for each user.

```
     Index  | user_name |  text  | label   |   text_list     |
       0    |    u1     |   t0   |   0     |        []       |
       1    |    u1     |   t1   |   1     |        []       |
       2    |    u2     |   t2   |   0     |        []       |
       3    |    u1     |   t3   |   1     |       [t1]      |
       4    |    u2     |   t4   |   0     |        []       |
       5    |    u2     |   t5   |   1     |        []       |
       6    |    u2     |   t6   |   1     |       [t5]      |
       7    |    u1     |   t7   |   0     |       [t3, t1]  |
       8    |    u1     |   t8   |   1     |       [t3, t1]  |
       9    |    u1     |   t9   |   0     |       [t8, t3]  |
```

A naïve way to do this would be to loop through each row and maintain a queue for each user. But the table could have millions of rows. Can we do this without looping in a more scalable, efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the solution posted here. I modified it slightly (since it assumed text field can be sorted) and was finally able to come to a working solution. Here it is:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, collect_list, slice, reverse
K = 2
windowPast = Window.partitionBy("user_name").orderBy("Index").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow-1)
df.withColumn("text_list", collect_list\
              (when(col("label")==1,col("text"))\
               .otherwise(F.lit(None)))\
              .over(windowPast))\
.withColumn("text_list", slice(reverse(col("text_list")), 1, K))\
.sort(F.col("Index"))\
.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spark version >= 2.4, there is a way you can try. Let's say `df` is your dataframe.

```
df.show()

# +-----+---------+----+-----+
# |Index|user_name|text|label|
# +-----+---------+----+-----+
# |    0|       u1|  t0|    0|
# |    1|       u1|  t1|    1|
# |    2|       u2|  t2|    0|
# |    3|       u1|  t3|    1|
# |    4|       u2|  t4|    0|
# |    5|       u2|  t5|    1|
# |    6|       u2|  t6|    1|
# |    7|       u1|  t7|    0|
# |    8|       u1|  t8|    1|
# |    9|       u1|  t9|    0|
# +-----+---------+----+-----+
```

Two steps :

1. get list of `struct` of column *text* and *label* over a window using `collect_list`
2. `filter` array where label = 1 and get the *text* value, descending-sort the array using `sort_array` and get the first two elements using `slice`

It would be something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, struct, expr, sort_array, slice
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# window : first row to row before current row
w = Window.partitionBy('user_name').orderBy('index').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df = (df
      .withColumn('text_list', collect_list(struct(col('text'), col('label'))).over(w))
      .withColumn('text_list', slice(sort_array(expr("FILTER(text_list, value -> value.label = 1).text"), asc=False), 1, 2))
      )
df.sort('Index').show()

# +-----+---------+----+-----+---------+
# |Index|user_name|text|label|text_list|
# +-----+---------+----+-----+---------+
# |    0|       u1|  t0|    0|       []|
# |    1|       u1|  t1|    1|       []|
# |    2|       u2|  t2|    0|       []|
# |    3|       u1|  t3|    1|     [t1]|
# |    4|       u2|  t4|    0|       []|
# |    5|       u2|  t5|    1|       []|
# |    6|       u2|  t6|    1|     [t5]|
# |    7|       u1|  t7|    0| [t3, t1]|
# |    8|       u1|  t8|    1| [t3, t1]|
# |    9|       u1|  t9|    0| [t8, t3]|
# +-----+---------+----+-----+---------+
```